# My footer disappears when I increase headheight

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr, geometry

I have created a custom simple layout with the `fancyhdr` package.  Because the header I must use is somewhat big, LaTeX instructed me to increase the `headheight` to at least a minimum value. The problem is, the footer gets moved down until it eventually disappears.

Here is a MWE, where the footer can still be seen at the bottom:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[landscape,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\setlength{\headheight}{60pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{This is header \\ This is header \\ This is header \\ This is header \\ This is header}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{This is the footer}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

First line of the document.

Second line of the document.

\end{document}
```

Now change `60pt` for `80pt` and compile again. Goodbye, footer!

Is there any way to fix this? I can't change the header, and I must have both header and footer.

Edit: The amount of support is incredible, 3 answers plus comments in one hour! Upvoting you all, and choosing most simple and idiot-proof solution as correct. Thanks!

Comment: Use the geometry options to change the headheight.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @PeterJansson Thanks! Quite a nice place to be in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may want to fiddle around with the `includeheadfoot` option that comes with the `geometry` package (and adjust your `geometry` settings accordingly to suit your needs):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,landscape,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\setlength{\headheight}{80pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{This is header \\ This is header \\ This is header \\ This is header \\ This is header}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{This is the footer}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

First line of the document.

Second line of the document.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you can add the option `showframe` to the `geometry`-package. It sould be easier to manually set the sizes.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you should leave to `geometry` all settings about page dimensions; setting `\headheight` *post facto* will ruin all the computations made by `geometry`.

Second, your setting of `\headheight` to 80pt is incompatible with the top margin you want, because the default head separation is 25pt and

> 80pt + 25pt = 105pt = 3.69cm

Your header is computed by `fancyhdr` to almost 71pt, actually; if you want to fit the header and have a top margin of 3cm, just do the exact computation for the headsep:

```
headheight=72pt, % give a bit more room
headsep=\dimexpr3cm-72pt\relax,
```

So finally you'll have

```
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,
  left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,
  headsep=\dimexpr3cm-72pt\relax,
  headheight=72pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
```

Here's a picture, where I used a slightly larger paper size, in order to show precisely what happens:

```
\usepackage[paperwidth=31.7cm,paperheight=23cm, % larger paper
  layoutwidth=29.7cm,layoutheight=21cm, % A4 landscape
  layouthoffset=1cm,layoutvoffset=1cm, % 1cm to crop on all sides
  left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,
  headsep=\dimexpr3cm-72pt\relax,
  headheight=72pt,showframe,showcrop]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
```

The crop marks show the "real" paper size which is A4 landscape.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is an exakt solution, without playing around to find the correct size.

You have to calculate the `totalheight` of the page, that is the *phyical paper height*, on DIN A4 it's `21cm`, minus the *top margin*, in your example that is `3cm`, minus the *headheight*, which is `80pt` in your example, minus the *bottom margin*, which is `3cm`, minus the `headsep` and finally plus the `footskip`.

By default, `headsep` and `footskip` are the same, so they cancel each other in this example.

`80pt` corresponds to `2.8169014084507cm`, according to 
[wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths#Units).

So your `totalheadheight` should be `12.1830985915493cm`, say `12.183cm` which sould be precise enough.

Now use `geometry` with the following options:

`\usepackage[landscape,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,includeheadfoot,totalheight=12.183cm,showframe]{geometry}`

Do not set the bottom margin directly with `bottom=...`, it is included in the calculation.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[landscape,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,includeheadfoot,totalheight=12.183cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\setlength{\headheight}{80pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{This is header \\ This is header \\ This is header \\ This is header \\ This is header}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{This is the footer}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

First line of the document.

Second line of the document.

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

**Edit** *: added `footskip` and `headsep` to the calculation*