# How to add a picture to fancyhdr *header* (and align in the top right)?

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, header-footer, fancyhdr

In the MWE below, the blue square aligns according to plan, whereas the dummy-image doesn't, see screenshots below. How to re-code so that the dummy-image "A" is aligned like the blue square?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% \rhead{{\color{blue}\rule{1cm}{1cm}}}

\rhead{\begin{picture}(0,0) \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}} \end{picture}}

% \rhead{\begin{picture}(3,3) \put(3,3){\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}} \end{picture}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: "A" outside]
[image: blue square inside]

Comment: Is there a special reason why you use `picture`?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Found that in the `fancyhdr` manual... but no, no special reason other than trying to come up with *some* solution... am just interested in a(n elegant) way to align the picture *just like* the blue square.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Don't use `picture` but instead directly use `\includegraphics`:

```
\rhead{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}
```

Now you should get a warning by `fancyhdr` about `headheight`:

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 24.93825pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

To get rid of this, add:

```
\setlength\headheight{26pt}
```

to the preamble.  <sub>This can be better done with the help of `geometry` package. That is a different story.</sub>

So the code will be:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength\headheight{26pt} %% just to make warning go away. Adjust the value after looking into the warning.
% \rhead{{\color{blue}\rule{1cm}{1cm}}}

\rhead{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}

% \rhead{\begin{picture}(3,3) \put(3,3){\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}} \end{picture}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! dunno how I missed trying that one... ;) +1 for the "heads up" on the `fancyhdr` warning !

Comment: @HarishKumar Believe it or not, this helped me a lot just for the warning!!!. I did not receive this warning, however only the first page was printed properly, for the rest of the document the footer was being displayed way too low. I added `\setlength\headheight{200pt}` and now all the pages display the same, is just question of customize the page geometry (I used the geometry package).

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Harish's answer, I recommend using the `geometry` package.

```
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm,headheight=26pt,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
```

The crucial points are setting `headheight` to a value bigger than the one in the warning (and omitting the `\setlength\headheight` command) and `includeheadfoot` if you use a footer at the same time.

Further details can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85179/45786) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/100403/45786).