# putting two distinct images on event and odd paged headers

Tags: graphics, header-footer, conditionals

I want to put images in the headers of all pages but the first page of a document.

Besides for the first page, on each and every odd page, I want one image; while on each and even page I want another image.

I tried to modify what is proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122934/how-to-add-a-picture-to-fancyhdr-header-and-align-in-the-top-right), but could not do so.

Comment: Show us, what you try so far. I guess that you have `twoside`  document. See `fancyhdr` documentation how it handle page headers at such documents (section *10 An example of two-sided printing, page 11 -- 12).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the page style elements are set when the page numbers are fully known, you can easily condition on whether or not you're on an odd/even page with `\ifodd\value{page} <odd page>\else <even page>\fi`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}% All pages will have a fancy page style
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
\fancyhead[C]{%
  \ifodd\value{page}
    \smash{\includegraphics[height=.8\baselineskip]{example-image-a}}% Center of Odd page
  \else
    \smash{\includegraphics[height=.8\baselineskip]{example-image-b}}% Center of Even page
  \fi
}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}% Centre of footer

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{%
  % Page style for first page
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhead[C]{First page}% Header
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}% Footer
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{firstpage}
\lipsum[1-50]

\end{document}
```

A separate `firstpage` page style is set up an used via `\thispagestyle{firstpage}`.

I've `\smash`ed the images, but you could consider changing the `\headheight` to suit the size of your image inclusion.