# Changing \headheight pushes footer off page

Tags: fancyhdr, geometry

Preface: NOT a duplicate of [My footer disappears when I increase headheight](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100402/my-footer-disappears-when-i-increase-headheight) - I tried the accepted answer here and still ran into issues.

---

I am using Overleaf to create some documentation for software, and using fancyhdr to customize the header and footers. My header contains images which makes the header somewhat large, so I get an error from LaTeX to increase headheight to a larger value. When I do increase this to the recommended 67pt, it removes the error, but pushes the footer off the page. At first glance, the question at the link I referenced above is a 1-for-1 mirror image of what I need, but I tried includeheadfoot, setting all to 1in margins through geometry, and the footer still runs off the page. I've looked at the fancyhdr documentation exhaustively and cannot find a solution. Below is a MWE, which pushes the footer off the page:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[includeheadfoot, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{lastpage}
\setlength{\headheight}{67pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} 

\fancyhead[C]{}
\lhead{\includegraphics[width=6cm]{image.PNG} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3cm]{image2.jpg}  \hfill \includegraphics[width=4cm]{image3.png}} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt} 
\fancyfoot[R]{\small ~Page \thepage~of \pageref{LastPage}} 
\lfoot{\small Collections Guide \\ Last Updated: 07/28/2017}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt} 

\begin{document}

First line of the document.

Second line of the document.

\end{document}
```

**How do I get rid of the \headheight warning while also keeping a footer which is at a 1 inch margin from the bottom?**

Note: I've only been using LaTeX for about 2 years and for really simple reports, so this is one of the more sophisticated projects I've done so far. I appreciate insight on how I can avoid this issue again in the future, and please let me know how I can edit this question to be more concise.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code example an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) (emphasis on _minimal_, i.e. remove unnecessary packages, options and definitions).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

give geometry the chance to know the headheight you are using by setting it with the geometry options:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot, margin=1in,headheight=67pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setlength{\parskip}{4pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{2pt}{2pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[C]{}
\lhead{\includegraphics[height=62pt]{example-image-duck}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{\small ~Page \thepage~of \pageref{LastPage}}
\lfoot{\small Collections Guide \\ Last Updated: 07/28/2017}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}

First line of the document.

Second line of the document.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! I added the includeheadfoot and moved the headheight to geometry as you suggested, and it worked beautifully. When I included the headheight outside of geometry, was I essentially overwriting the parameters I initially ascribed within the geometry package?

Comment: The overwriting is not the main problem. The values not independant: when you enlarge the headheight you also need to shorten the textheight. geometry is doing this for you, but only if you  give it all the values.