Afterpage does not work with the newest pdftex version
I was interested in having different margins for the first page, and saw this answer which seems to do exactly what I was trying to achieve. It uses the packages geometry and afterpage. The solution works perfectly fine under pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 and under the newest LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0, but breaks in the newest pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26.
Upon further trial and error, I have noticed that afterpage itself seems to have an issue. The MWE below intends to print the text after the first page, i.e., on top of the second page. This works on the builds I mentioned but not on the latest pdfTeX.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}
\afterpage{\Huge On top of the second page}
\lipsum
\end{document}

The log is:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.ltd.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/afterpage.sty) (./test.aux)
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
[2] [3] (./test.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/am
sfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsf
onts/cm/cmr17.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (3 pages, 31310 bytes).
SyncTeX written on test.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on test.log.


you can't change margins using afterpage. The version of pdftex/luatex will not be relevant, what might be relevant is the latex release date, but it would only ever "work" by chance on some documents if you got lucky at the page break. In principle this has never worked or been supported.

to have a different top margin on the first page, don't use afterpage or geometry, just use \vspace*{some length} to start the document further down the first page.

Well, the answer I linked claimed it could work, and it works with the two versions I mention, I don't really understand how the version is irrelevant. At any rate, afterpage has a problem with the latest pdfTeX build. I tried without involving geometry to see if afterpage had the desired behavior, and it does not. I'm modifying my question to clarify this point.

the version of the pdftex binary is not relevant as that code hasn't changed what matters is the page breaking code in latex which is releated to the latex  release as shown in teh log as 2024/06/01 or whatever.

Hmm then what does the version mean at all? I'll add the log of the current problem, but I don't have the log with the previous version as I have updated my distribution.

I get this output from your new example with an up to date texlive 2024 with  LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2  You still have not said which latex release you are seeing broken output

I have LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1, see the log I just added.

iIf I use texlive 2023 instead of texlive 2024 I get the same  output I show in my answer using texlive 2023 and LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1 and Package: afterpage 2023/07/04 v1.08 After-Page Package (DPC)

That's odd: your log looks good, my texlive 2023 is a bit older and texlive 2024 a bit newer and both work....

@DavidCarlisle is that the pdftex that broke afterpage?

oh you mean it could be the pdftex binary after all? I completely forgot about that!

Looks like it: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1311.
I have downloaded MacTeX just today and made sure to get rid of older installations, I am updating all packages using TeX Live Utility at this moment. I'm not sure why I would not be up to date after that, so hopefully the bug disappears.

@Cryme sorry about incorrectly insisting the pdftex version didn't matter.  But bugs in the tex binaries are so rare. That was I think the only tex release in 30 years that broke a core latex package (and it only lasted a few days before being fixed)  so I forgot all about it.

No worries, I was really not aware of what was important to mention. At any rate, I have fully updated my distribution and it works properly! Now it's Overleaf's turn to update their distribution... Thank you for your helpful answers.

@DavidCarlisle it looks as if overleaf is really using the broken pdftex.

oh b***r  you could tell @yo' ....

Update
For a few days in March 2024 just after the initial texlive 2024 release a broken pdftex binary meant that afterpage did not work. there is no way to work around this using tex macros you need to update your system and get the updated tex binary.
https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1311

original answer before Ulrike reminded me of issue 1311
Changing geometry in \afterpage is definitely not supported and in general it can't work. In the specific case that you are just changing the top margin not the left and right margin, it could work but in that case it is much better to use no package at all and simply use \vspace on the first page.
the posted example produces this on an up to date LaTeX

That is pdflatex using
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2

However it is much simpler (and a lot more robust)
to get the same output using

\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    top=3cm,
    hmargin=1in,
}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=8cm}
\vspace*{5cm}

\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}


That is true in this specific case, but I was just using the MWE of the linked answer. I am actually interested in changing the headheight, and \setlength{headheight}{...} does not work as well as \newgeometry{headheight=...} since it will push the footer. See for instance https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/503379/155855.

again it would be better to use \thispagestyle on the first page rather than \afterpage. trust me iI wrote afterpage I have a fair idea what it does and I tried to warn people in its documentation that it's scarily fragile and will break at the first opportunity.

@Cryme but I suspect Ulrike might be right and this is the one question out of 250,000 or so questions on the site where the specific tex binary does make a difference....

@Cryme sorry you need to update your tex system the breakage here was classed as not my fault https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/1311

Ah I did not know that, thank you for the package! I have tried using \thispagestyle but somehow the same pushed footer issue arises. At any rate, is there no way to specify a different geometry for the first page only?

I'll tinker around more with thispagestyle and if the issue still arises, I will open another question.
