# The number of page goes down,down and down

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr

I have `\pagestyle{fancy}` with usual settings. 
And names of my chapters sometimes are so huge (above the top line) that somehow the number of page (which is in foot of the page) is going down, down and down with each page until it'll disappear. It is ridiculous to see at the first page approximately 2cm between number and end of the page and 1mm on the page 100 and nothing at the last page.

```
%document information
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

% packages
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts,longtable} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amstext,amssymb,amscd} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                           
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[margin=2.3cm, footskip = 0.5 cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{tikz}                                   
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{bm}                         
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,.6}

% page settings
\frenchspacing 
\parindent=1cm
\sloppy
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

% other settings
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfobjcompresslevel=9

\hypersetup{
  pdfsubject         = {Matan},
  pdfstartview       = {FitH},
  pdfborder          = {0 0 0},
  bookmarksopen      = true,
  bookmarksnumbered  = true,
  bookmarksopenlevel = 2,
  colorlinks = true,     linkcolor  = darkblue,
}


%own commands

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{fancy}

\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\foreach \n in {1,...,36}{\include{chapters/chapter\n}}

\end{document}
```

And don't blame me for using text about Eminem for test in future math book. :)

PS. In `chapters/chapter\n` there are just texts about Eminem with no commands expect `\chapter{}`

[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I am sure not many will note the word EMINEM in a Cyrillic font text ;-) But your question is not quite unclear unless you provide a compilable version of your document that shows this issue

Comment: Welcome, the title put a song into my head: *The wheels on the bus go round and round...* ;-)

Comment: Try to prepare a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) (<- simple method linked) and show it to us. Right now, we cannot have a clue. Check the log file for `fancyhdr` warnings concerning the headheight, though.

Comment: Have I done your request?

Comment: @Dida: Da, choroscho ;-)

Comment: Could be http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85179/38080 ? You should provide headheight space for the biggest of your headings... (or cut them, with the `\chapter` optional argument).

Comment: Off-topic: Please load `hyperref` at the end of the preamble, not somewhere surrounded by a bunch of other packages!

Comment: Why? 
Is it convenience or real benefit?

Comment: @Dida: In many cases **benefit** since `hyperref` redefines a couple of things to make the whole hyperlinking work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a clear warning about `headheight` being to small (see the `.log` file.) It's recommended, depending on the current very long chapter titles, that the headheight is set to about 35pt at least.

In my opinion, `footskip` is too small here, I increased its value to `1cm`.

Now the page number position remains fixed.

```
%document information
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}

% packages
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsfonts,longtable} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amstext,amssymb,amscd} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                           
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,margin=2.3cm, footskip = 1 cm,headheight=36pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{tikz}                                   
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{bm}                         
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,.6}

% page settings
\frenchspacing 
\parindent=1cm
\sloppy
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

% front page
\author{Андрей Диденко}
\title{Подготовка к ГОСу по МатАнализу
\date{16 Апреля 2016}.
\LaTeX}
\usepackage{hyperref}    
% other settings
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfobjcompresslevel=9

\hypersetup{
  pdftitle           = {GOS_MatAn},
  pdfauthor          = {Didenko Andre},
  pdfsubject         = {Matan},
  pdfstartview       = {FitH},
  pdfborder          = {0 0 0},
  bookmarksopen      = true,
  bookmarksnumbered  = true,
  bookmarksopenlevel = 2,
  colorlinks = true,     linkcolor  = darkblue,
}


%own commands

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{plain}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\epigraph{Дорогой моей и любимой Настеньке посвящается}{Диденко А.А.}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{fancy}

\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\foreach \n in {1,...,36}{\chapter{A long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long chapter title which is totally boring}\blindtext[10]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yeap. Thanks. 

It works. 
I am so dissapointed that I wasted a lot of my time for this easiest problem.

Comment: You may also want to provide the option `includeheadfoot` when loading the `geometry` package.

Comment: Can you answer me another little question? (I am not very good at LaTeX as you can see)

I have a title page. 
But if you look at it more carefully - you will see, that cyrillic symbols are very wrong and crooked.

But Main Part is Ok.

Comment: @Dida: Actually, the **rule** is: One question -- one answer and if it's ok, accepting them, then asking a new question ;-)

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for correcting my stupid typo!

Comment: Oh, no. It is so little and unimportant that I don't want all people to waste their time

Comment: @Dida: Go ahead ... and don't forget the `acceptance` rule nevertheless ;-)